# Java Puzzle moving left and right in an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of integers. Starting from the first position, I then add or subtract the value at the given index to move around in the array. The purpose of the puzzle is to get to the last element of the array which is 0. I’m aware that this problem is already solved here with recursion, but I’m supposed to give a non-recursive solution.
To avoid an infinite loop, I make a condition

```
if (a[index] == a[index+temp])
```

and the code works fine when I pass an array like this:

```
int a [] = { 3, 1, 2, 3, 0 };
```

But then I pass `int a [] = {3, 6, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 0 }` and it tells me that the puzzle does not have a solution, which is not true. 
Here is part of my code:

```
       int temp;
       int index = 0;

       while (index < (a.length-1) && index >= 0)
            {
                temp = a[index];

                if ((index+temp) <= a.length-1 )
                {
                    if (a[index] == a[index+temp]){
                        solution = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    index = index + temp;
                }
                else if ((index-temp) >=0)
                {

                    index = index - temp;
                }

        }
```

I attach a photo from my assignment which explains the behavior of the algorithm. 
[image]

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm in-hand a bit more? I don't really understand how the "Move right" and "Move left" actually happens... (As in: why "Move right" in step 2 stops at 1...?)

Comment: He is supposed to try both directions I think, whichever leads to the solution.

Comment: @MordechayS When I am at the starting position, the value is 3. I can only move three position to the right. At position a[3], the value is 1, so I can move right or left.

Comment: @q212 do you have a strategy for each step? Like "Always try going left, and if failed - go right"?

Comment: Your code is not going to work without some kind of backtracking logic.

Comment: @MordechayS, that's what I can't figure out. After checking the condition if (a[index] == a[index+temp]), I need another condition to make it move right if it can.

Comment: This looks like a directed graph path problem, where each position in the array is a node, and from each node you can get to one or two other nodes.  Start with your initial node, then keep a running set of which nodes you can get to from there.  No backtracking needed.

Comment: Can't use graph :( We haven't covered them yet. I'm allowed to use stack, queue or array.

Comment: You do not need to use a real graph, the array you got is a graph already. You should just use a graph-based algorithm which can be array/set/stack/queue/whatever based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is basically a directed unweighted graph. Each index is connected with 1 or 2 other indexes.

Now, having that in mind, you can solve this problem easily with a "[breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)" algorithm which works pretty well without recursion.

Here is pretty verbose implementation example: https://ideone.com/yzeBzz

```
List<Integer> solve(int... a) {
    //Value in each element is the index, from where we can come here
    int[] path = new int[a.length];
    Arrays.fill(path, -1); //No index is accessible yet

    //Queue of positions that were visited from somewhere, but nothing was tried to be 
    //visited from them. At the beginning, 0 is in the list, because it's starting point.
    //Then, if we visit index 3, it is added to this list for later processing.
    Queue<Integer> posQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    posQueue.add(0);
    path[0] = 0; //0 index is accessible from itself, this is starting position

    while (!posQueue.isEmpty()) {
        int pos = posQueue.remove();
        int prPos = pos - a[pos];
        int nxPos = pos + a[pos];
        if (prPos >= 0 && path[prPos] == -1) {
            path[prPos] = pos;
            posQueue.add(prPos);
        }
        if (nxPos < a.length && path[nxPos] == -1) {
            path[nxPos] = pos;
            posQueue.add(nxPos);
        }

        if (path[a.length-1] != -1) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (path[a.length-1] == -1) {
        return null;
    }

    //Collect the path
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int idx = a.length-1;
    while (idx != 0) {
        result.add(0, idx);
        idx = path[idx];
    }
    result.add(0, 0);
    return result;
}
```

As with any breadth search algorithm, the complexity is O(N).

Comment: I think I win by 2 seconds... :)

Comment: Yup, it would've taken me more than 2 seconds to find that link and add it.

Comment: bezmax, thank you for your answer. My fault is that I didn't mention that I can only use stack, queue and array for the solution.

Comment: Your limitation makes no difference to my solution. You can easily use this with one secondary array containing the position of the index with a shortest path to the index.

Comment: @q212 Added some implementation example for you.

Comment: @bezmax, THANK you so much! That's exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

This might work:

```
boolean solve(int... a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1 << a.length; i++) {
        int pos = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j)) == 0) {
                if ((pos -= a[pos]) < 0) {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if ((pos += a[pos]) >= a.length) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (a[pos] == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, shmosel!

Comment: @shmosel This is basically a bruteforce with some bitmask voodoo. You could have used an array instead of the bitmask getting much clearer code and the same horrible O(2^n) complexity. Try running it with 30 integers for example.